# PendingIntent не работает в уведомлении (IllegalStateException)

Tags: android, android-sdk, kotlin

Есть кастомное уведомление.

Макет:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewNotification"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="@string/custom_notify_test"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/notify_btn"
                android:layout_width="128dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="@string/ok" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Создание уведомления в `Activity`:

```
val notificationIntent = Intent(this, TestReceiver::class.java)
                notificationIntent.putExtra("test_message", "TEST MESSAGE")
                notificationIntent.flags =
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                notificationIntent.setAction(ACTION_ID)
                val flags = PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                val contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    this,
                    1,
                    notificationIntent,
                    flags
                )
                val notificationChannel: NotificationChannel =
                    NotificationChannel(
                        CHANEL_ID,
                        CHANEL_NAME,
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
                    )
                notificationChannel.description = "Test"
                val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
                    getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
                val notificationLayout =
                    RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.custom_notification_layout)
                    notificationLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.textViewNotification, "TEST 2")
notificationLayout.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notify_btn, contentIntent)
val builder = Notification.Builder(this, CHANEL_ID)

                builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                    .setStyle(Notification.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
                    .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)                
                var notification: Notification = builder.build();                
                notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification)
```

`BroadcastReceiver`, при помощи которого я отлавливаю `PendingIntent`:

```
class TestReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if ((intent != null) and (context != null)) {
            if (intent?.action.equals(MainActivity.ACTION_ID)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, intent?.getStringExtra("test_message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Его регистрация в `Activity`:

```
val filter = IntentFilter(ACTION_ID)
val receiver = TestReceiver()
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

По коду вроде бы всё правильно. Но, по клику на кнопке в уведомлении ничего не происходит, а должен появляться `Toast`.

Вместо этого при открытии уведомления в logcat появляется:

> 2019-12-15 22:14:26.268 644-673/com.android.systemui W/MessageQueue:
>   Handler (android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler) {e36500e} sending
>   message to a Handler on a dead thread
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler) {e36500e} sending message to
>   a Handler on a dead thread

Что я делаю не так?

P.S. Попытки спрашивать в гугле и самостоятельные эксперименты пока результатов не принесли.

**UPDATE**
Зарегистрировал receiver в манифесте и поменял `ACTION_ID` (было "100", стало "rtyghnjlkj152bjgjgu")

```
<receiver
    android:name=".TestReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="rtyghnjlkj152bjgjgu" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Теперь пишет просто:

> 2019-12-15 22:36:42.019 425-1024/? W/AMessage: failed to post message
>   as target looper for handler 0 is gone

.

Comment: А вы же, судя по коду, `MainActivity` просите запустить - при чём здесь ресивер? Ещё проблемс: `PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE` - просит не создавать новый `PendingIntent`, а вернуть ранее созданный или `null`, если не нашлось идентичного. Замените на `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` или более подходящий.

Comment: @woesss, поправил (см. вопрос), но всё равно не заработало. В logcat пишет ошибку.

Comment: Ресивер лучше зарегистрировать в манифесте - уведомления обычно выводят, когда активностей нет на переднем плане и живучесть им не гарантирована. А что за плеер? - у вас в вопросе нет на него даже намёка.

Comment: Что за плеер я сам не пойму. Поменял ACTION_ID и плеер исчез из ошибок. Осталась одна строчка (см. вопрос), но приложение пока не работает как надо.

Comment: Поменял ACTION_ID на нормальный с точки зрения Android (com.example.notifysample.TEST_ACTION) начал в отладке попадать в ресейвер.

Answer (score 0):

После регистрации `BroadcastReceiver` в манифесте (см. вопрос) и изменения `ACTION_ID` на `com.example.notifysample.TEST_ACTION` проблема с `PendingIntent` как таковым решена.

Метод `onReceive` выполняется.

P.S. По `Toast` возможно будет задан отдельный вопрос.

P.S.S. Огромное спасибо **woess** за консультацию!